# How to connect DatePicker functionality to a Twitter Bootstrap input element?

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use this feature: http://keith-wood.name/datepickBasics.html

Documentation: http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

How can I implement it in my input field?

```
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input01">Registration Date</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="input01"
                        name="regDate">
                </div>
            </div>
```

According to the datePicker documentation it says :

Connect the datepicker functionality to your input field or division/span.

```
$(selector).datepick();
```

You can include custom settings as part of this process.

```
$(selector).datepick({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
```

Comment: What did you use as `selector`

Comment: You could consider a bootstrap datepicker http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the "selector" part of the function call with an actual CSS Selector. In your case use

```
$("#input01").datepick({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your selector variable set?

If not, you need to use something like:

```
$("#ID_SELECTOR").datepick();
```

or

```
$(".CLASS_SELECTOR").datepick();
```

As a suggestion, why not use the official jQuery datepicker library?

Answer (score 0):

this should put it on your input.. see the '#input01', that tells the date picker to be applied to the element with an id of input01 which is in your code

```
$('#input01').datepick();
```

also, you might want to check out https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker as its a bootstrap friendly datepicker, and blends in nice.